# More optimal way of selecting only max records for two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, max

I am currently wanting to select the current top 25 ranked teams from my MySQL db with this query:

```
SELECT team_school, team_name, rank, rank_name, week_key, year_key
FROM teams t JOIN weeklyrankings wr ON t.team_key = wr.team_key
JOIN RankType rt ON wr.rank_type_key = rt.rank_key
WHERE wr.rank <= 25
      AND wr.week_key = (
        SELECT MAX(week_key)
        FROM weeklyrankings
      )
      AND wr.year_key = (
        SELECT MAX(year_key)
        FROM weeklyrankings
      )
GROUP BY t.team_key
ORDER BY wr.rank;
```

It works, but I am guessing the two subqueries in the WHERE clause are not optimal. I tried replacing the two subqueries with:

```
AND wr.week_key = MAX(wr.week_key)
AND wr.year_key = MAX(wr.year_key)
```

but get an error saying `[HY000][1111] Invalid use of group function`

So what would be a better way of ensuring I get the max records of both year && week?